# Launcher Activity not calling when app came from background to foreground in android

Tags: android

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TescoWelcome">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.myrealapp.android.PAY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
          
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.myrealapp.android.GHS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.myreal.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/clubcard"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:scheme="real-myapp" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
<activity
            android:name=".features.welcome.view.WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MYREALAPP" />
```

This is my activity I am trying to update the app from google play from the current version to a new version which is in play store what happened in that case when we kill the app and try to update the app in that case launcher activity call but when we go in welcome activity and minimize app then go in google play try to update the app in that case what happened Launcher activity on creating not calling it to call welcome activity which is next of splash activity. please I don't know why this behavior in the android app ideally it should call launcher activity which is Splashscreen. please help me in this issue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` multiple

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya sorry it was my mistake I edited